# Encryption support on Symbian S60 (3rd Edi) and Decrypt at C#.Net

Tags: c#, c++, cryptography, symbian, s60-3rd-edition

I am developing simple app for S60 3rd Edition FP2 platform and as per current requirement i would like to perform Encryption (custom key based) at client end (i.e in my Symbian S60 based application) and Decryption at server end (definitely using the same key) (i.e C#.Net/VB.Net)

On Symbian platform i have tried AES using CPaddingSSLv3, DES using CPaddingPKCS7 and able to encrypt and decry pt on symbian platform, but as per my requirement i need to perform decryption at server end (i.e using C#.Net/VB.Net)

Is there any specific Encryption and padding combination which will fulfill this requirement or any reference of document or pointer on this will helped...

Comment: I am not familiar with Symbian, but just based on what you wrote I would concentrate on AES with CPaddingPKCS7 for maximum interoperability. You will also need to be extremely diligent in ensuring that the keys are exactly the same on each platform.